# Is it everyone's dreams or everyone's dream?

Tags: grammar

Is it everyone's dreams or everyone's dream? I thought about it and I am really unsure which is correct I think "everyone's dreams" is the correct one, but I am not sure.

For example:

> God can control everyone's dreams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. In this sentence, *dreams* (plural) is the correct choice because everyone has their own dreams. Also, each person may have more than one dream. In the context of controlling dreams, you are talking about what people unconsciously imagine at night- one normally has multiple dreams per night.

However, if you were talking about a dream that is common to everyone - as in a fantasy - then you would use the singular. For example:

> It is everyone’s dream to become a movie star.

While everyone dreams independently of everyone else, in this example the specific fantasy is shared by everyone, so the singular, *dream*, is correct here.